# Piezoelectric Harvester Circuitry

Tags: circuit-design, piezo, energy-harvesting, piezoelectricity, piezoelectric-effect

Can anyone tell me what type of circuit is used in this piezoelectric harvester? And if possible, could you also provide a diagram of it when connected to battery?

[image]

Comment: I would also like to add how you distinguish the positive charges from negative charges since I’m also planning to connect it to a battery and a full bridge rectifier.

Comment: looks DIY ... you will have to contact the maker to get the circuit diagram for that one

Comment: how do you know that it is an energy harvester? ... it could easily be a speaker that someone puts under their bed pillow

Comment: `I would also like to add  ...` ... that added question does not belong in a comment ... this is not a forum ... all of your question belongs at the top of the page ... please edit your question

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Talha-Ashraf/publication/338797132_Energy_Harvesting_through_Floor_Tiles/links/5e69d5ca458515c5de6288c9/Energy-Harvesting-through-Floor-Tiles.pdf?origin=publication_detail